# Regex to avoid equal and sequence digits

Tags: php, regex

I was searching for a regex which matches my requirement. But I couldn't find an exact one .

My requirement is

Add validation check to avoid Phone numbers with:

> 1) 6 digits equal (e.g. 000000 ; 111111)
>    2) sequence numbers (7 digits) (e.g.
>   1234567 ; 7654321)

I tried and got this piece of code finally

```
if (preg_match('/(\d)\1{5}/', $phone)) {    
     echo "Invalid Phone number";
}
```

But it matches only the first case. Hope some one will help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide more sequences that should be invalid regarding your 2) option.  What output you want from: `9012345` , `7890123` , `1098765` ?

Comment: Regex does not allow you to "code" a sequence of digits. You would need to enumerate them, like `'/(\d)\1{5}|1234567|7654321|etc./'`

Comment: Is '5678901' valid or not?

Comment: @NareshRavlani It is valid

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those times that I'd break away from regex.

This will perform your expected validation (and includes "around-the-clock" number sequences).

[PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d9914d67ac526899401eb2b00b6f16983685508)

```
$phone='000000';
$len=strlen($phone);
$rnd_the_clk='0123456789012345';
if(($len==6 && $phone==str_repeat($phone[0],6))  // length is 6, check only one integer used
    ||
   ($len==7 && (strpos($rnd_the_clk,$phone)!==false || strpos($rnd_the_clk,strrev($phone))!==false))){ // length is 7, check sequential
    echo "invalid";   
}else{
    echo "valid";
}
```